# How to flatten a stream of Single<R>

Tags: java, java-stream, rx-java

I have this code

```
    public Stream<PaymentEntity> getPayments(List<String> paymentIds) {
        return paymentIds.stream()
                .flatMap(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id))

}
```

`paymentsRepository.getById(id)` is returning `Single<PaymentEntity>`

But i got compile time error

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that
>   Single conforms to Stream

Edit, to anyone asking about `Single`  http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html

Comment: What's a `Single<PaymentEntity>` and how do you intend to convert it to a `Stream<PaymentEntity>`?

Comment: The function given to `flatMap` must return a stream. You need to convert your `Single` to a `Stream`.

Comment: Why does it need to be flattened at all if no stream is returned? And what's `Single`? Does it have some getter that returns a `PaymentEntity`?

Comment: Looks like the code should be using regular `map`, such as `map(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id).get())` (assuming there's `Single.get()`).

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
return paymentIds.stream()
            .map(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id).toBlocking().value());
```

Or in `rxjava 2` you can use :

```
 return paymentIds.stream()
            .map(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id).blockingGet());
```

---

After comment I think you can go with this solution :

```
 List<PaymentEntity> result = new ArrayList<>();
 paymentIds.forEach(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id).toObservable().subscribe(result::add));
 return result.stream();
```

Comment: I think you mean blockingGet(). and i cannot use it, to not block the execution of calling thread

Comment: @Melad Basilius I don't know blockingGet() it is toBlocking()

Comment: @YCF_L maybe we are talking about different things, can you please provide any documentation link about toBlocking(), i need to read about it

Comment: @Melad Basilius are you using `import rx.Single;` or another library?

Comment: @YCF_L  `rx.Single` is rxjava1 I think. And OP is probably on rxjava2

Comment: @YCF_L 'import io.reactivex.Single;'

Comment: @Melad Basilius sorry I'm using phone for that I dont give a quick answer, check my edit hope this can help you

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution:

```
public Stream<PaymentEntity> getPayments(List<String> paymentIds) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(paymentIds)
            .flatMapSingle(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id))
            .toList()
            .blockingGet()
            .stream();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until the current `Single` in the lambda signals a success value using `.blockingGet()`:

```
return paymentIds.stream()
            .map(id -> paymentsRepository.getById(id).blockingGet());
```

Or you can wait until all the reactive chain signals a success value in this way:

```
return Observable.fromIterable(paymentIds)
            .flatMapSingle(paymentsRepository::getById)
            .toList()
            .blockingGet()
            .stream();
```

Consider also to use `Flowable`: unlike `Observable`, it supports backpressure strategy.